# proof question about an infinite sums

Tags: sequences-and-series

I once saw a place one interesting question, the question is:

proof that if $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n$ diverges, then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{a_n}{a_1+\cdots+a_n}$ diverges.

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845278/

Comment: is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{a_n}{a_1+\cdots+a_n}=+\infty$? or $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{a_n}{a_1+\cdots+a_n} $ diverges??